# external table file to load omitting columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to upload data from file to external table in oracle, but do not need all the columns defined in the file,
So far i've tried this

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl(
   col1 number,
   col2 varchar2(10),
   col3 varchar2(10),
   col4 varchar2(10),
   col5 varchar2(10)
)
 ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL(
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY MY_DIR
     ACCESS PARAMETERS(
       RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        (
           col1 ,
           filler ,
           col3 ,
           col4 ,
           filler
         )
    )
 LOCATION(
     'myfile.txt'
       )
)
```

by consulting the table generates this error

> ORA-29913: error al ejecutar la llamada de ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN 
> ORA-29400:
>   error de cartucho de datos 
> KUP-04043: table column not found in
>   external source: col2

file structure: 0111,column,testing,name,address

Comment: show the contents of myfile.txt , based on the error message the fields are not comma delimited

Comment: file contenst this: 0111,column,testing,name,address @Ricardo C

Comment: why would you call those columns 'filler' and not col2 and col5 respectively? and by file structure, you mean "file contents"? is that the text inside the file?

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the easy way? If you accept Ricardo's correction your External Table works. Then add a view with the columns you need:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl( col1  NUMBER
                     , col2  VARCHAR2( 10 )
                     , col3  VARCHAR2( 10 )
                     , col4  VARCHAR2( 10 )
                     , col5  VARCHAR2( 10 )
                      )
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
   (TYPE oracle_loader
         DEFAULT DIRECTORY MY_DIR
            ACCESS PARAMETERS
               (
       RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        (
           col1 ,
           col2 ,
           col3 ,
           col4 ,
           col5
         )
    )
         LOCATION( 'myfile.txt' ));

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW what_i_need
AS
   SELECT col1, col3, col4 FROM test_tbl;
```

Comment: well so I can not do as Ricardo says is is optimizing the database as there are files that have more than 400 fields, but I think if terminare taking that path